# Populating Custom List with Intent Extras - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am an application, which is basically an empty activity (empty list-view) where in the toolbar there is an Add button, clicking the button takes you to another activity with two edit text fields and a button (to submit the activity, in other words send the intent extras to the first activity). I want to take those input (both are strings) from that activity and display them in the list-view in the first activity.

I have made the toolbar and the button, and placed the custom list-view with its adapter in the first activity, and in the second activity I created the necessary views and along with the intent (for passing the two strings).

The problem is, that in the second activity, when I pass the intent extras to the first activity, a new list-view gets created every time instead of appending the list-view.

Can someone help me append the intent extras rather than creating a new list every time the user adds the two inputs?

This is the onCreate method in the first activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_countries);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null)
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    populateList();

}
```

This is the populateList();

```
    public void populateList(){
    Bundle countryData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (countryData == null){
        return;
    }
    String country = countryData.getString("country");
    String year = countryData.getString("year");

    ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new CustomAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    countryList.add(new Country(country, year));
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country>{


    public CustomAdapter() {
        super(MyCountries.this, R.layout.list_item, countryList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null){
            view  =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Country currentCountry = countryList.get(position);
        TextView countryText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
        countryText.setText(currentCountry.getCountryName());

        TextView yearText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yearOfVisit);
        yearText.setText(currentCountry.getYear());

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

}
```

And this is the onClick() for submitting the input:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String country = addCountry.getText().toString();
    String year = addYear.getText().toString();

    Intent result = new Intent(this, MyCountries.class);
    result.putExtra("country", country);
    result.putExtra("year", year);
    startActivity(result);
}
```

Thank you very much. 
Any help, or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen when you click `back` from your 2nd Activity or also when you click the submit button?

Comment: When I click the submit button